1970's or 1980's era horror movie with a monster that gets happy at the sight of a studded glove
I have a memory of a horror movie that I believe to be circa 1970s or possibly early 1980s. 
It was in English.  
The part that I remember was as follows:
A guy that was dressed in a studded jacket or had studded gloves (think biker gear) was being attacked by a monster.  He throws his arms in front of his face as the monster is about to attack.
The monster upon seeing the gloves gets a memory flashback.  The flashback involves someone with similar studded jacket or gloves feeding the monster when it was a baby.
Flash forward and instead of attacking, the monster gets all happy and starts acting like a puppy.  He whines and wags his tail.  The guy in the jacket/gloves kind-of stands there stupefied by what just happened.

TerrorVision, (1986)

On an alien planet named Pluton, an alien garbage disposal converts a
  monstrous mutant called a Hungry Beast into energy and beams it into
  space. Meanwhile, on Earth, the Putterman family is getting satellite
  television, courtesy of a temperamental DIY antenna. The reception is
  poor at first, but suddenly strengthens when a bolt of the alien
  energy hits the dish.
...
Soon after though, they encounter the Beast in another room. It chases
  after them, but relents at the sight of O.D.'s heavy metal
  paraphernelia, which he finds appealing due to its resemblance of his
  caretaker's gloves.


well played: https://youtu.be/gUD0jgnoS-8

That's it!!! Thank you!!!
